# Wrap a function in try catch using Higher order functions in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I have a set of functions that have different signatures and parameters, but all of them could throw an exception. Instead of adding try-catch in each of them, I want to write an inline function that takes a function as an argument and calls this function within a try-catch block, and returns are certain types wrapping the exception.

```
// first function. 
fun foo() -> String

// second function. 
fun bar(argument: String) -> Boolean


// Result Type
sealed class Result<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}

// Wrapper Function
inline fun <T, R> safeCall(call: (T) -> R): Result<R>


// This Returns Result<String>
safeCall { 
    foo()
}

// This Returns Result<Boolean>
safeCall { 
    bar()
}
```

I am facing an issue while implementing the `safeCall()` method. Ideally, I would want this to work for any underlying function. I can either make it to work for `foo()` or `bar(argument: String)` but not for both.

```
inline fun <T, R> safeCall(
    call: (T) -> R, // This syntax forces to to have only one parameter.
): Result<R> {
    return try {
        val result: R = call() // This throws compilation error. 
        Result.Success(result)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Result.Error(e)
    }
}
```

PS - Pretty new to Kotlin and Functional Programming.

Comment: I don't see a question, is this a rhetorical argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure! This sounds like a reasonable design pattern. Just a few notes.

```
inline fun <T, R> safeCall(call: (T) -> R): Result<R>
```

`safeCall`'s argument shouldn't itself need arguments. It's just a block of code that we're going to call, so this would be a more appropriate signature.

```
inline fun <R> safeCall(call: () -> R): Result<R>
```

Now as for how to actually implement it, it sounds like you have all of the right ideas. Just try to call the function inside of an actual Kotlin `try` block.

```
inline fun <R> safeCall(call: () -> R): Result<R> {
  try {
    return Result.Success(call())
  } catch (e: Exception) {
    return Result.Error(e)
  }
}
```

Then you can call it as

```
safeCall { 
  foo()
}

safeCall { 
  bar("Example Argument")
}
```

Remember that `bar` takes an argument. Even if that argument is defined outside of the `safeCall` scope, it still works through the magic of closures.

```
val x = "This works :)"
safeCall { 
  bar(x)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Silvio. This is exactly what I wanted. I made a mistake passing a generic <T> in the call(), forcing me only to pass one argument.

Answer (score 3):

By implementing your `Result` class you really seem to duplicate a class from stdlib named... well, `Result` :-) Your `safeCall` is then named `runCatching`:

```
// Result<String>
runCatching {
    foo()
}

// Result<Boolean>
runCatching {
    bar("Example Argument")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. runCatching() seems exactly what I am trying to implement. Thanks for suggesting this. I will start using this. 

I was going to make this function non-inline and catch the error and generate error messages on top of it by taking another inline function. But I think making an extension function of Exception to get meaning fun error messages will make more sense here.